# How to formulate weighted differential entropy (multivariate) in integral form?

Tags: integration, matrix-equations, information-theory, entropy

Differential entropy of one variable is
$$h(x_i) = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) \ln p(x) dx,$$

For the entropies of multiple variables $\mathbf{X} = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_K\}$, we can place them together in a vector
$$\mathbf{h}(\mathbf{X}) =
\begin{pmatrix} h(x_1) \\ h(x_2) \\ \vdots \\ h(x_K) \end{pmatrix}$$

If we want to weight the entropies in the vector element by element as a summation, a weight vector is pre-multiplied

$$\begin{pmatrix} w_1 \enspace w_2 \enspace \dots \enspace w_K \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} h(x_1) \\ h(x_2) \\ \vdots \\ h(x_K) \end{pmatrix} $$

Above shows the weighted entropy vector operation in **matrix notation**. How can I instead write this **as** **one integral**? Is the following correct?

$$h(x_i) = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} w_i \cdot p(x_i) \ln p(x_i) dx_i$$

If so, this where I'm stuck:

- should I add a second subscript to the $p_i$'s since we are integrating them observation by observation, whereas $w_i$ is left as is because we are integrating weights variable-by-variable?
- should there instead be a double integral because of this?
- should I leave the $i$th weight outside of the integral because it's not stochastic (random) like everything else inside of the integral?

*(edited $H$ to $h$ because the first represents discrete entropy and the second is for differential entropy)*

Comment: The inner product is just $\sum w_i H(X_i).$ So you have the integral $-\int \sum_i w_i p(x_1, \dots, x_n) \log p(x_i) \,\mathrm{d}x_1\dots\mathrm{d}x_n$. As to where you put the $w_i$s, that's a choice of presentation, so it's entirely up to you. Typically all that is expected is that it makes sense at a glance and is treated consistently throughout the document.

Comment: why are there joint probabilities outside of the logarithm, but  not inside?

Comment: Because you asked about representing it as a single integral. Basically - $ \int p(x_i) \log p(x_i) \,\mathrm{d}x_i = \int p(x_1, \dots, x_n) \log p(x_i) \,\mathrm{d}x_1 \dots \mathrm{d}x_n,$ since all the $x_k$s for $k \neq i$ don't feature in the log, and you marginalise over them (or, if you prefer, use Fubini's theorem integrating $x_i$ last). Then the inner product is $ -\sum_i w_i \int p(x_1, \dots, x_n) \log p(x_i) \,\mathrm{d}x_1\dots\mathrm{d}x_n,$ and moving the sum in gives one integral. If we had joint laws in the log, we'd end up computing the joint entropy of all of the $X_i$s.

Comment: Oh also - just a notation thing. The standard convention is to denote differential entropy as $h$ and not $H$. This is mainly to highlight the fact that differential entropy is a different object than discrete entropy (for instance it can be negative).

Comment: thanks, who would've known. i was starting to realize though that there is a discrete number of weights, $K$. and therefore the integral wouldn't run from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ like i showed in the first place.. besides this, i think this is the first time to see the summation operator be used side-by-side with an integral sign. I always thought math is either discrete or continuous but can't be represented as both at the same time?

Comment: Well, $\sum$ is just notation for adding many things. Surely you're comfortable with the idea of writing $f_1(x) + f_2(x)$ for two continuous valued functions of a continuous valued variable $x$. I could equivalently write this as $\sum_{i = 1}^2 f_i(x)$, no big deal. You must also have come aross $\int f_1(x) + g_2(x)$ (for instance when integrating polynomials), and here again you could include a summation sign. The pulling the summation and the $w_i$s in and out is just linearity of integration (i.e. $\int (f(x) + g(x))= \int f(x) + \int g(x)$ and $\int (a\cdot f(x) ) = a \int f(x)$).

Comment: What's happening is that there is a finite (or countable) number of continuous objects, so both discrete operations (such as adding some of them up), and continuous operations (such as integrating over them) make sense, and you can mix these in a semantically consitent way. Note that having a 'discrete' group of continuous objects is very common - for instance, each point in the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a list of $n$ (continuous) values.

Comment: such great explanations, thank you. especially when given with examples

Comment: I'm wary of explaining how and why marginalization is done, so I'm guessing it would be alright to leave it at $-\Sigma_i w_i \int f(x_i) \ln f(x_i) \hspace{1mm} dx_i$, while exponential entropy would be $-\Sigma_i w_i \hspace{1mm} e^{\int f(x_i) \ln f(x_i) \hspace{1mm} dx_i}$?

Comment: I haven't really come across the term exponential entropy (is $\exp(-h(X)$?), but both the expressions you wrote make sense, sure.

Comment: I realized my mistake after posting that, and you're right, the negative sign has to be moved from the front to the exponentiated term. anyway the following has more about it https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481284/what-is-exponential-entropy